# createFromFormat is not working properly

Tags: php, datetime

I' am using WordPress custom field plugin. The value is stored in the database in this format **22/04/2014 2:29 pm** something is wrong in my createFromFormat that its not working properly.

**Database Value**

```
22/04/2014 2:29 pm
```

**PHP Code**

```
$schedules_arrival = get_field('schedules_arrival');
$datetime = new DateTime();
$schedules_arrival_date = $datetime->createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:mm tt', $schedules_arrival);
echo $schedules_arrival_date = $datetime->format('d M Y H:i');
```

**Above Returns**

```
22 Apr 2014 21:02
```

**Should Return**

```
1 Apr 2014 06:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `tt` use `a` for "pm". `t` stands for the number of days in the month.  Also, you only need one `m` for minutes:

```
$schedules_arrival_date = $datetime->createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:m a', $schedules_arrival);
```

See [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for a list of the identifiers.